# Visual Studio 2015 Hangs when creating new xamarin app

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I could have sworn the options last time I did this was `Blank App..` but now I'm seeing `Cross-Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native)` but regardless, when I create a new project using `Cross-Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native)`, I get a `Creating Project` and then followed by a `Microsoft Visual Studio is busy...` dialog and it will just hang there indefinitely. I've even let it go for almost an entire day and it still doesn't create the project. My goal here is to create a blank Xamarin app which uses forms and platform level code as well. Is what I tried to create doing that? If so, how can I make it not hang. If not, what do I need to do to create the blank xamarin app which does what I described above?

A github or whatever link to a blank app would honestly suffice at this point. But whatever help can be provided is greatly appreciated. Screenshot of it not being responsive below.

[image]

Comment: It was me , i would back and format the device and try the new VS 2017 and you can set it up this way 
http://motzcod.es/post/158155898027/setting-up-vs-2017-for-xamarin-dev

 or install  VS 2015 again make sure you fullfil the requirements here 
http://motzcod.es/post/157589380047/xamarin-cycle-9-preparing-machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I reinstalled an old version of Xamarin (27 Jan 2017) and it works fine now.
As I had another problem with the latest version, this version is fine for me.

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42437303/2046795)